# How to name dataframes as a function of first occurrence in a group

Tags: python, pandas

How to loop over a data frame and create new dataframes, named after a pattern and including that pattern only.

For example, for a dataframe like this:

```
      df= pd.DataFrame({'X': ['hello', 'hi', 'hello', 'salut','hi', 'hi',
      'hello', 'salut'], 'Y': [1, 4, 3, 2, 9, 0, 4, 3]})

        X       Y
   0    hello   1
   1    hi      4
   2    hello   3
   3    salut   2
   4    hi      9
   5    hi      0
   6    hello   4
   7    salut   3
```

I want to have

```
  df_hi:
           X    Y
       0   hi   4
       1   hi   9
       2   hi   0

  df_hello:
           X       Y
       0   hello   1
       1   hello   3
       2   hello   4

  df_salut:
           X       Y
       0   salut   2
       1   salut   3
```

My data is very large and I'd like to name the new dataframes automatically, inside a for loop.

Comment: Generally, I would store them as a dictionary: `{k:v for k,v in df.groupby('X')}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['hello', 'hi', 'hello', 'salut','hi', 'hi', 'hello', 'salut'], 'Y': [1, 4, 3, 2, 9, 0, 4, 3]})
>>> for label in df.X:
...     exec("df_{0} = df[df.X == '{0}']".format(label))
... 
>>> df_hi
    X  Y
1  hi  4
4  hi  9
5  hi  0
>>> df_hello
       X  Y
0  hello  1
2  hello  3
6  hello  4
>>> df_salut
       X  Y
3  salut  2
7  salut  3
```

For efficiency, maybe you would like to change `for label in df.X` into `for label in list(set(df.X.values))`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating new dataframes, you could filter the existing one.

```
df[df['X'] == 'hello']
```

will give you one of the dataframes you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `groupby()` and storing your results in a dictionary where the keys are the unique values of your `X` column and the values are the filtered dataframes (and preserves the original indices), like so:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('X')))
```

Then, to retrieve your dataframe corresponding to `hello`, you can simply perform:

```
dfs['hello']
```

Yields:

```
       X  Y
0  hello  1
2  hello  3
6  hello  4
```